# Poner botón Cancelar en formulario personalizado de Drupal con PHP

Tags: php, funciones, botón, drupal, submit

He creado un modulo personalizado en Drupal 10 (module custom) en PHP. He añadido el botón Enviar y funciona correctamente. Ahora quiero añadir otro botón que sea Cancelar o Volver y me redireccione al formulario anterior y no veo la forma de hacerlo. He buscado por todo internet y he probado de todo, pero nada me funciona. Quizás un experto en PHP y Drupal me pueda ayudar.

Para añadir el botón Cancelar he puesto el siguiente código en la función buildForm y el botón aparece correctamente en el formulario:

form['actions']['cancel'] = array(

```
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value'  => t('Cancel'),
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 15,        
    '#limit_validation_errors' =>[],    
    '#submit' => array('node_form_cancel'), 
  );
```

En la ultima linea, llama a la función node_form_cancel, la cual contiene el siguiente código:

function node_form_cancel(){

```
$backurl ="servidor/drupal/es";     
drupal_goto($backurl);
```

}

También he probado con el siguiente código y tampoco funciona:

public function node_form_cancel() {

```
$url = 'http://servidor/drupal/es';  
return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

}

El error que lanza es:

TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "node_form_cancel" not found or invalid function name in call_user_func_array() (line 114 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php).

He creado la funcion call_user_func_array() y tampoco funciona.

function call_user_func_array(callable $callback, array $args): mixed{}

La sensación que tengo es que explota siempre en el submit del botón. Da igual que función pongas, siempre explota ahí.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a crear un botón Cancelar o volver?